# Sending parameters to web page and have them validated

Tags: java

I have a java problem that I hope to get some help with.
In my application I get a random captcha  image from a website. The user writes the captcha letters in a text area and click a button to validate the code.

The code + the date and time the captcha was recieved from the website are added as parameters to the web site. The website writes "true" if the code is correct, otherwise "false".

My problem is that the website Always writes "false", even if the code is correct.

I don´t even know if I have the right approach?
At least I know that the URL is correct (The format is:  http://xxxxxx.php?code=ddd&date=Sat%2C+14+Feb+2015+21%3A14%3A20)

EDIT:
I do not need to validate the code, only send it to the webpage and there the webpage automatically validates it. All I have to do is to send the parameters (code + formatteddate) to the webpage.
Any suggestions, please?

In test class:

```
public void validateURL() throws IOException {             
        String code = textArea.getText();           //Get code from textArea
        String validation = myCaptcha.validateCode(code);  //Call to method validateCode();
        switch (validation) {
            case "true":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Right code");
                break;
            case "false":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "wrong code");               
                break;
        }
    }
```

In class Capthca:

```
public String validateCode(String code) throws IOException {             
        String link = "http://xxxxxxx.php?"+"code="+code+"&date="+formattedDate;
        URL url = new URL(link);        
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        //connection.setDoInput(true);
        //connection.connect();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text = br.readLine();
        while (text != null) 
        {
            sb.append(text);
            text = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        connection.getInputStream().close();

        return sb.toString();
   }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line after the `link` variable in `validateCode`, does the `code` and `link` variables contain what you expect?

Comment: [I suggest you to read this](http://www.sitepoint.com/easy-jquery-php-captcha/)

Comment: @Janos Yes the url is exactly what I expect it to be.

Comment: @NeerajJain  see my EDIT above. I do  not need to validate the code.

Comment: Print the `link` variable and copy-paste it into a web browser. See if you can get expected result. If not, then may you are using the API incorrectly (like missing parameter), and URL encode bug is also a possible reason ...

Comment: @MengWang I have pasted it into a web browser and it writes "false". Do you think the url might be wrong after all?

Comment: @user2939293 Maybe. I think you need to read the document of the API again and follow their example. Make sure you can reproduce the examples.

Comment: @MengWang if I look at my url it looks exactly as in the example I have gotten from my instructor. I'm not sure that's the problem. 
Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user2939293 I'm not familiar with URL class, but it may do URL encoding again. You can try not to  encode the date `formattedDate` yourself.